# Running "convert" from ImageMagick on Windows

Tags: imagemagick

I installed ImageMagick and see several .exe's in the install directory (dcraw, ffmpeg, hp2xx, and magick.

But most the examples I see are like this, using a "convert" command.

```
 convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 hatching_orig.jpg -thumbnail '100x100>' \
          -background skyblue -gravity center -extent 100x100 pad_extent.gif
```

I'm totally unclear if magick.exe replaces convert, or if convert is a subcommand of the magick.exe.

This is what I tried and the response:

```
"c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" -define jpeg:size=510x510 Sacred_Geometry_Flower_Of_Life_BlueGreen_Test1.jpg -thumbnail '100x100>'-background skyblue -gravity center -extent 100x100 pad_extent.gif
magick.exe: unable to load module 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275.
magick.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
```

Comment: In IM 7 magick replaces convert, but for the other functions such as identify, mogrify and montage, you must put magick before them. I am not a windows user, but it looks like you did not install IM properly. I suspect you did not install all the needed delegates in this case libjpeg. How did you installl IM? Did you do if from the ImageMagick binary or source? If the latter, then you would be better installing from binary. Perhaps there are switches in the install program to install delegates that you did not check. The first command above is in Unix syntax for IM 6.

Comment: I think Windows dislikes single quotes (`'`) too, so replace those with double quotes (`"`).

Comment: If you want to be able to use the old style of **ImageMagick** commands which begin with `convert`, you must tick/check the box called *"Install legacy commands"* when installing. As Fred said, `convert ...` becomes `magick ...`, `identify ...` becomes `magick identify ...`, `mogrify ...` becomes `magick mogrify ...`. The changes were introduced to reduce pollution of the namespace and to avoid collisions with a pesky Windows command also called `CONVERT.EXE` which converts FAT filesystems to NTFS.

Comment: If you let imagemagick add itself to the environmental path you can replace "c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe" with magick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the install, I didn't check the box circled below: 
[image]

I'm still unclear if I could say `magick.exe convert` but all the examples just show running `convert`.

The second problem was security; I found another stackoverflow, but now I can't find the URL for it.  They suggested giving user=everyone full control to the Windows install directory.  Not a good thing to do, but I was more concerned with a quick solution at the moment.

@Mark in the comment above mentioned the quotes.  I thought he meant around the directory name, but it turns out the the -thumbnail parms need to be in double quotes instead of singles quotes (at least on Windows).

Comment: There is no ImageMagick.exe. It would be magick.exe or convert.exe. I do not recommend using both. magick.exe would run IM 7. convert.exe would run IM 6. Prefacing the other commands such as identify, mogrify, etc with magick.exe would run IM 7. Leaving off magick.exe would run those other commands using IM 6. magick.exe convert is likely the same as convert.exe. I do not use Windows, so am not sure where the .exe is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have added Imagemagick to the system path so you only need magick. You have not installed legacy file so you can not use convert. Do not use '' anywhere but "" Using "" will still work on Linux systems. \ is a Linux line continuator and I belive you should use ^
I install imagemagick and it works; no changing of permissions etc.

This should work:

```
magick -define jpeg:size=200x200 hatching_orig.jpg -thumbnail 100x100> -background skyblue -gravity center -extent 100x100 pad_extent.gif
```

Why not try something simple first to prove to yourself it works?

```
magick hatching_orig.jpg pad_extent.gif
```